# How to get post request to display in the console

Tags: node.js, rest, api

//Need some help on api in console. I need help figiuring this out

```
var options = { method: 'POST',
      url: URL + 'i/pushes/prepare?api_key=411f2297c3b58651019b3086e17bbfc7',
      qs: { api_key: '411f2297c3b58651019b3086e17bbfc7' } };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
      if (error) throw new Error(error);

      console.log(body);
    });
    //get request
    var options = { method: 'GET',
      url: URL + 'o?method=devices&api_key=411f2297c3b58651019b3086e17bbfc7&app_id=5bb537f0b5af9c065041f52d',
      qs: { app_id: '5bb537f0b5af9c065041f52d', api_key: '411f2297c3b58651019b3086e17bbfc7', method: 'devices' } };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
      if (error) throw new Error(error);

      console.log("DEVICE DATAS+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
      console.log(JSON.parse(body));
      console.log("Device info", ["2018"]["4"])
    });
```

//Please any help is appreciated

Comment: What do you receive now?

Comment: Receiving the following in terminal: DEVICE DATAS+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++!!!!!!!1
{ '2018': 
   { '10': 
      { '4': [Object],
        '9': [Object],
        '10': [Object],
        '11': [Object],
        Unknown: [Object] },
     Unknown: { u: 1, t: 96, n: 1 },
     w40: { Unknown: [Object] },
     w41: { Unknown: [Object] } },
  meta: { devices: [ 'Unknown' ] } }

I would like to access the info and pull out the data. I trued to do ["2018"]["10"], however its not working

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON.stringify` to get your response data like this,

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(body));
```

Alternatively you can use `console.dir` like this where you don't have to use `JSON.stringify`,

```
console.dir(body);
```

Hope this helps!